# What happens at the minimal distance in unbound central-force orbits?

Tags: classical-mechanics, orbital-motion

The rate of change of the radius of an object subject to a central potential U(r) is given by

$$\dot{r}=\pm \sqrt{E-V_{eff}(r)}$$

where  $V_{eff}$ is the effective potential. An unbound orbit is obtained when $E>V_{eff}$ for $r\in [r_{min},\infty]$.

When the object closing in from infinity reaches $r_{min}$, we have $\dot{r}=0$. Then, the object turns and goes back to infinity.

How? Clearly since $\dot{r}=0$, I can just say that at any future time the radius does not change.

How does $\dot{r}$ start from negative, then becomes zero at $r_{min}$, then becomes positive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object turns around because $\ddot r>0$ at $r=r_\mathrm{min}$.

We can explicitly show this. Starting from
$$
\dot r = \pm \sqrt{2(E-V_\mathrm{eff}(r))}
$$
(your expression is missing a factor of 2), we can differentiate again with respect to time and use the chain rule to obtain
$$
\ddot r = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\frac{-V_\mathrm{eff}^\prime(r)\dot r}{\pm\sqrt{E-V_\mathrm{eff}(r)}} = \frac{-V_\mathrm{eff}^\prime(r)\dot r}{\dot r} = -V_\mathrm{eff}^\prime(r),
$$
where $V_\mathrm{eff}^\prime(r)=\mathrm{d}V_\mathrm{eff}(r)/\mathrm{d}r$. But at $r=r_\mathrm{min}$, $V_\mathrm{eff}^\prime(r)<0$ (the potential is rising as radius drops), so $\ddot r>0$.